# Issue with starting application Spring MVC + Grunt + JHipster + AngularJS

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, gruntjs, jhipster

I am using *Spring MVC* in my RESTful web aplication that I run using *Maven*. I have two profiles:

1. *Development* profile, which works properly on hsql and oracle. I successfully build my application, and it works great.
2. *Production* profile, where I am using ***Grunt*** Javascript Task runner, for minification Javascript, CSS and HTML files.

When I run my application in "prod" profile, *Maven* is building my application using *Grunt*. Grunt does his job properly, he change my files based on configuration in *Gruntfile.js*. Files are changed properly and saved in *dist* folder, and new ***index.html*** file is created with references to newly generated *CSS* and *Javascript* files. I build my app successfully.

The problem is, when I start my app on http://localhost:8080, I only load *css* and *javascript* files from *dist* folder and make call **GET login**, but I am stuck here (using Firebug in Firefox browser):

[image]

Not one REST call is made to my application. When I start application in working *dev* profile, first call is for *rest/authenticate*, but in *prod* profile, I never gets there. When I turn on logs for spring framework, I can see that my *AntPathRequestMatcher* gets stuck after checking my favicon.ico, and never gets to *rest/authenticate*. It seams like my *javascript* code is not initialized properly so he can make REST calls?!

I think I made my configuration properly in my *WebConfigrurer.java*, *SecurityConfiguration.java*, *DispatcherServletConfiguration.java*... But I can't resolve this issue.

If anyone had a similar problem, I would appreciate if he/she helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds like your javascript isn't running. Any errors in the firebug console?

Comment: No, there are no errors. Firebug console is empty. I should have call for rest/authenticate and for getting en.json (translation file), but I'm stuck before that. 

Do you have idea what might be a problem, because I've checked .java configuration, Gruntfile.js, and everything seems to be ok?

Comment: Does your SecurityConfiguration filter out your js folder? I.e:
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**");
    }

Comment: Yes. In my Security Configuration I have these filters:
 web.ignoring().antMatchers("/bower_components/**").antMatchers("/fonts/**").antMatchers("/images/**").antMatchers("/scripts/**").antMatchers("/styles/**").antMatchers("/i18n/**");

Comment: If i understand correctly grunt minifies your files and stores them in your 'dist' folder for production environment? So css files get stored in /dist/styles, javascript files get stored in /dist/scripts, etc?
If so then i think you should change the antMatchers accordingly.

Comment: When I set my configuration like this:
 web.ignoring().antMatchers("/dist/bower_components/**").antMatchers("/dist/fonts/**").antMatchers("/dist/images/**)".antMatchers("/dist/scripts/**)".antMatchers("/dist/styles/**").antMatchers("/dist/i18n/**")
I still have the same problem. I can't load files that are created in dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the size of the script.js is 0 bytes?!
Did you checked the content?

May be, it's possible that your scripts are not between (I assume you are using Jhipster v1.X.X because you have script.js instead of app.js and vendor.js...)

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
```

and

```
     <!-- endbuild -->
```

?

Grunt only packages all scripts that are between these two tags

Comment: Hi eplog. My script and css files are between build tags in my index.html. I checked it. And in dist folder I have files generated and changed properly using Grunt. But when i run my application, it makes call for CSS and JS generated file, but those files are empty (0B). There is no response (content) in those REST calls. Do you have idea what might be the problem? Files are created properly, but not loaded on the right way...

Comment: Hi, to get it right: is your script.js empty (when you manually open it) or is it not empty and only the REST call is empty?! If it is the first one, its grunt, if it is the last one, i can image that it is a caching problem

Comment: It is the second problem, REST call is empty. I always clear cache in browser before I run application. So I think that can't be the problem...

Comment: Hi eplog, I found solution for the problem. It was caching problem. I have a class in Spring MVC configuration called CachingInitHttpResponse, where I set few parameters for caching response in compliance with this article: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9 

Thank you for answering on my question, it helped me to resolve this issue. Regards

Comment: Hi, good to hear that you found a solution! I had no time to answer your previous comment, but i also guessed that it is a server side caching and not a browser side caching problem...